# Safari <li> text changes width on hover

Tags: html, css, safari

In Safari 10.0.3 (12602.4.8) simple unordered list items changes it's width if li element have on hover style

HTML:

```
<ul class="cc-menu">
  <li>Apple</li>
  <li>Orange</li>
  <li>Pineapple</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.cc-menu {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
.cc-menu li:hover {
  color: #888;
}
```

Before hover:

[image]

After hover:

[image]

JsFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/nresg4hr/

Is there any way to avoid such behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far best workaround I've found is to declare own style for list items in css.

```css
.cc-menu {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none; /* suppress browser list style */
  background: #000;
  padding: 0 0 0 24px;
  color: #fff;
}
.cc-menu li:hover {
 color: #888;
}
/* declare own list style */
.cc-menu li:before {
  content: '\2022';
  padding-right: 8px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="cc-menu">
  <li>Apple</li>
  <li>Orange</li>
  <li>Pineapple</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this style

```
.cc-menu {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
.cc-menu li:hover {
  color: #888;
  display:block;
}
```